# Only first letter by DataFormatString

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik-grid, dataformat

I have a column when I bind enum:

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="N/U" DataMemberBinding="{Binding VehicleCondition}" ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=CarSalon.VehicleConditions}" IsGroupable="False" DataFormatString="" />
```

How can I display only first letter by DataFormatString?

Or maybe another solution without DataFormatString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you want to implement a `ValueConverter` which will look something like this (using LINQ string extensions):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return ((string)value).First().ToString();
}
```

Obviously if your input value (`VehicleCondition`) isn't a string you'll need to do something more complicated.

Your XAML will become something like this:

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="N/U" DataMemberBinding="{Binding VehicleCondition, Converter={StaticResource initialLetterConverter}}" ...
```

If you need to access other information about the item not just the `VehicleCondition` then you can change the binding to:

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="N/U" DataMemberBinding="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource initialLetterConverter}}" ...
```

which will bind to the object. Your converter then becomes something like:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var carSalon = (CarSalon)value;
    string result = string.Empty;

    if (carSalon != null && <whatever else you need to test>)
    {
        result = temp.VehicleCondition.First().ToString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

where you can do any checks on the object or get other properties of the object you need.

Comment: It doesn't work because it converts only DataMemberBinding, and then can't match it with ItemsSourceBinding :/